# How to snap mesh onto another and have all its faces snap onto its surface

Tags: mesh, snapping

I am not quite sure how to word this well so apologies if it comes off as confusing, but I am looking for ways to snap a mesh onto another mesh, but having it snap every part onto the mesh's surface rather than just regularly snapping it.

For example in the image example below, I want the white stripe mesh to get deformed so it fits onto his body proportions and snaps onto the surface of his body appropriately. [image]

Comment: I think you might be interested in the shrinkwrap modifier. Use it in combination with placing your object using snapping turned on.

Comment: I tried using it but the results are bit off https://imgur.com/a/A6SvCaP

Comment: Add a small amount of offset in the modifier

Comment: I tried that too but parts of it wind up not being quite snapped to the body then https://imgur.com/2FYpO6x I assume I'd have to edit that part manually?